# Django admin crashes after Save and Continue redirects to None instead of id of the primary key. Help?

Tags: mysql, django

I installed Django for the first time yesterday and trying it out in earnest today. I'm only planning to use it for the beautiful admin interface, Zend Framework for the rest.

I imported an existing table `event` into the admin. There's no join needed. But the primary key is not 'id' it's called "event" (following [this naming convention](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2008/10/26/the-power-of-a-good-sql-naming-convention/)). I obviously don't want this column's id# to appear in the data entry form.

Everything works fine, EXCEPT when adding a new event, I click Save and Continue Editing, it adds the event, but redirects the URL to 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/events/event/None/
and spits out this error

```
ValueError at /admin/events/event/None/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'
```

This is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    event = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=500,verify_exists=False)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    ACTIVE_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'InActive'),
        (1, 'Active'),
    )
    active = models.CharField(max_length=1, default=1, choices=ACTIVE_CHOICES)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'event'
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how to fix this?

Comment: Does it work when you just create a new event (hitting "Save" instead of "Save and Continue Editing")?

Comment: Yes it does...I'll try your answer right now, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want the PK to be an `AutoField` instead of an `IntegerField` so Django will automatically fill it in for you.  Otherwise you *have* to do it yourself in the save method or the admin interface:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a fix, but hopefully it can help shed light on this situation.

Behind the scenes when you hit "Save and Continue" what's happening is there are 2 URLs that are accessed...

```
/admin/events/event/add/
/admin/events/event/{id of newly created element}/
```

If you look at the error your getting, the URL that is' choking on is '/admin/events/event/None/'.  Note how where the id should be there is the value of 'None'?  It means that when a new record is created it probably isn't having a value set for 'event' (the pk).

If you were to check your SQL database you'd probably see the event column was null.

Steve Losh just posted the code (as I was typing) on how to solve this so I'll end my answer here.

Comment: Thanks for responding T. I noticed that, but what puzzled me was that it added the record correctly. But now that you explain it, all makes sense. A NULL value in MySQL on an autoincrement key works...

I thought django would pull the LAST_INSERT_ID (can you link from a comment? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html). 

I hope it isn't calculating the highest id and incrementing it and sending the value to MySQL. That can fail sometimes.